# How to remove java project from eclipse without affecting clearcase repository

Tags: eclipse, clearcase

When I try to delete a java project I receive attached error.

Should I disconnect the project first before deleting it. I want to delete the project from my workspace and recreate it again from the clearcase repository.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually due to a `view_server.exe` process still locking a file.

You should disconnect first, but also make sure the view has been stopped.
It is best to stop the view from the command-line:

```
cleartool endview -server yourView
```

Then, you should be able to delete the project from Eclipse without problem (unless you have other processes, not related to ClearCase, keeping an handle on one of your project files).