# Will this delete a project in clearcase?

Tags: clearcase, rad

Will deleting a project locally through eclipse also delete the project in clearcase?

I'm a new user of clearcase coming a from a cvs/subversion background. I want to re-create an already created project from clearcase. I think I should delete the project and then re-create the project from clearcase. But I do not want to cause any adverse effects when I delete the project, as it seems clearcase maintains a constant connection to locally checked out project.

What is the proper way of re-creating a clearcase project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If:

- your Eclipse has the [ClearCase plugin](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/downloads/07/cc_eclipse3_2/clearcase_plugins.html) activated
- your `.project` and `.classpath` Eclipse files are within a ClearCase view (very important, see for instance "[imported Eclipse project not linking to ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432945/imported-eclipse-project-not-linking-to-clearcase/4433604#4433604)")

Then deleting the project through Eclipse would delete the project in ClearCase: the surest way to check that would be to display the version of the parent directory of said .project file once deleted: that parent directory history should include as its latest version one "unreferencing `.project`".

But a simpler way is to keep those two operations (delete in Eclipse and delete in ClearCase) separate:

- delete the project from the workspace in Eclipse (without deleting the actual file)
- go in your ClearCase explorer and delete those files.

Comment: Thanks. my Eclipse has the ClearCase plugin activated. So best practice to remove my project locally without affecting project on clearcase(so I can recreate project from ClearCase repo) is to : Delete my project from Eclipse and  when Eclipse offers option to delete files also on file system, to which I should select "No". Then just recreate my project from ClearCase, which should replace any local changes I have made with latest from ClearCase repo ?

Comment: @user470184: yes, that is the general idea, but remove all elements from ClearCase first, then "add to source control" your new Eclipse project in ClearCase.

Comment: Why would I remove all elements from ClearCase? I need to keep the ClearCase files un-modified, so not remove them. I think I am missing a step.

Comment: @user470184: at least remove the `.project` and `.classpath`, in order to recreate the Eclipse project, keeping the same source in place. Then you can import an existing project into your Eclipse workspace.

Comment: every time manually removing .project and other meta files is very hard. Delete everything from project is not working as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985118/how-to-remove-java-project-from-eclipse-without-affecting-clearcase-repository) . How to remove all the meta files and retain all the files under ClearCase from Eclipse?

Comment: @ernesto "very hard"? What issue did you encounter?

Comment: We are running Eclipse from a server and the source resides in ClearCaase. Asking every user to go to their project directory and manually remove .project/.cproject/.settings files from server is not elegant. Most of the users are not even aware of what these meta data files are for. I have posted a seperate question asking the same [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586514/how-to-remove-eclipse-project-related-files-without-deleteing-the-source-from-ec)